# Find Velocity for the ball elastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, momentum

[image]

The question is to find the initial velocity of the ball and the answer for this question is option 2 (which i highlighted).

I am trying to use this formula which is $v^2=u^2+2as$

The acceleration for the ball= = $g$

The collision is elastic collision and $h$ is Height, $L$ is Length.There is no friction

I am quiet confused how to get the "s" which is displacement.

The ball follows the trajectory as shown – initial position to A and then to B

Anyone can help me solving this question?

Comment: You can try  using projectile formula...$$\int Y=L\tanθ-\frac{gx^{2}}{2v^{2}\cos^{2}θ $$ for both cases....

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the symmetry available to you because of the collision being elastic.

Try to solve the question by removing the wall... and then argue that since the wall doesn't change the speed ( conservation of energy or momentum ), thus the wall is immaterial ( it only changes direction ).